# How get full path to file build.gradle by Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, path, gradle

I need create file in my java-project near buiid.gradle-file. I must create task (Groovy task) in build.gradle-file, my task must create file near buiid.gradle in my project, but I do not know - how do get path to buiid.gradle-file, that is putting in my project.

How get full path to file buiid.gradle by Groovy? Help me, please.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

1. If you look at the [Working With Files](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) page, you can simply use the `file()` method that is a part of the `Project` object.
2. If you look at the [Project DSL Docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html), you should see the [`projectDir`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:projectDir) property. Thes properties are available throughout the `build.gradle` script.

They can be used, respectively, like this:

```
task myTask << {
    println file('.')
    println projectDir
}
```

Would output

```
/full/path/to/your/project/
/full/path/to/your/project/
```

Where that directory contains the `build.gradle` file where the task is located.

Comment: You can also start with related section in userguide - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html

Comment: @Radim Yes, that's probably a better way if you're going to be creating files. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

To get a handle to the java.io.File that represents the currently-executing .gradle file:

```
def file = buildscript.sourceFile
```

In my case, I needed the directory of that script so I could apply other configuration from the same directory:

```
def buildCommonDir = buildscript.sourceFile.getParent()
apply from: "$buildCommonDir/common.gradle"
```

This approach works with **any** .gradle file, not just build.gradle.