# How can I find the path of the current gradle script?

Tags: file, gradle

We use some Gradle base scripts on an central point. This scripts are included with "apply from:" from a large count of scripts. This base scripts need access to files relative to the script. How can I find the location of the base scripts?

Sample for one build.gradle:

```
apply from: "../../gradlebase/base1.gradle"
```

Sample for base1.gradle

```
println getScriptLocation()
```

Comment: Do you want the full path of `base1.gradle` in `base1.gradle`?  you can just get it from `buildscript.sourceFile`. or do you want the relative path used by the calling script? if you know that the caller is a `build.gradle` file you can get it from `buildFile`. can you add sample output to your question

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer.

Comment: Also in this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446643/573389

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if this is considered an internal interface, but `DefaultScriptHandler` has a `getSourceFile()` method, and the current instance is accessible via the [`buildscript`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Script.html#org.gradle.api.Script:buildscript) property, so you can just use `buildscript.sourceFile`. It's a `File` instance pointing at the current script

Comment: It's in the API at https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/dsl/ScriptHandler.html#getSourceFile-- , so I think this is safe to rely on.

Answer (score 5):

I'm still not sure if I understood the question well but You can find path of current gradle script using following piece of code:

```groovy
println project.buildscript.sourceFile
```

It gives the full path of the script that is currently running. Is that what You're looking for?

Comment: This return the location of the project build script. In the sample from build.gradle. Also if I call it inside the base1.gradle. But I need the location of base1.gradle. This is also expected. It is the buildscript of the project. And not the current script.

Comment: You need the location of `base1.gradle` in `build.gradle`, yes?

Comment: No, I need the location of base1.gradle inside base1.gradle. build.gradle does know of course the location of base1.gradle. See my workaround.

Comment: No I understand. This is not possible. Gradle sets workingDir for every applied script equal to the one that is invoked. It's impossible without a workaround You made or any other.

Comment: The right answer is without 'project'. Only 'buildscript.sourceFile' return the right path.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pulling it off the stack.

```
buildscript {
    def root = file('.').toString();
    // We have to seek through, since groovy/gradle introduces
    // a lot of abstraction that we see in the trace as extra frames.
    // Fortunately, the first frame in the build dir is always going
    // to be this script.
    buildscript.metaClass.__script__ = file(
        Thread.currentThread().stackTrace.find { ste -> 
            ste.fileName?.startsWith root 
        }.fileName
    )

    // later, still in buildscript

    def libDir = "${buildscript.__script__.parent}/lib"


    classpath files("${libDir}/custom-plugin.jar")
}
// This is important to do if you intend to use this path outside of 
//   buildscript{}, since everything else is pretty asynchronous, and
//   they all share the buildscript object.
def __buildscripts__ = buildscript.__script__.parent;
```

Compact version for those who don't like clutter:

```
    String r = file('.').toString();
buildscript.metaClass.__script__ = file(Thread.currentThread().stackTrace*.fileName?.find { it.startsWith r })
```

Comment: I replace ".startsWith root" with ".endsWith '.gradle'" and it work. Very cool hack!. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround is to inject the path from the calling script. This is ugly hack.

The caller script must know where the base script is located. I save this path in a property before calling:

```
ext.scriptPath = '../../gradlebase'
apply from: "${scriptPath}/base1.gradle"
```

In base1.gradle I can also access the property ${scriptPath}

Comment: Have You worked out anything else? I may try but I feel that I don't understand the question well. Any minimal working example?

Comment: This answer is my current workaround. The question is how can I detect the location/path of the current script? The script is checkin in a repository and has a different location on any developer system.

Comment: Do You have any minimal working example? Just to know what exactly You need to achieve?

Comment: I have add a minimal sample.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is set a property for the location of A.gradle in your global gradle settings at: {userhome}/.gradle/gradle.properties

Comment: This can be a solution if the script exists only one. If I have checkout the workspace multiple times for different branches this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for this scripts in the relative path like:

```
if(new File(rootDir,'../path/A.gradle').exists ()){
    apply from: '../path/A.gradle'
}
```

Comment: I does not understand your answer. From your sample. How find I inside the script the A.gradle the path to A.gradle. This need I to load A.gradle.properties.

Comment: You have to know possible location of A.gradle in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has not been tested with 'apply from', but has been tested with settings.gradle

Gradle has a Script.file(String path) function.  I solved my problem by doing

```
def outDir = file("out")
def releaseDir = new File(outDir, "release")
```

And the 'out' directory is always next to the build.gradle in which this line is called.

Comment: Yes, it is ever related to the main build.gradle and never to inlined gradle files.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were using 'apply from'

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for gradle kotlin DSL file location as we do for shell scripts like this

export LNX_SPI_ROOT="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"