# Android.Gradle: Is it possible to get current module name programmatically?

Tags: android, gradle

Android Studio 2.3.3, Gradle 4.2.

In my **app/build.gradle**

```
myProp.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("app/keystore.properties")))
```

OK. It's work. 
But I want to remove hard code name of module (in this example this is a "**app**")

So I need to get current module name programmatically.
Something like this:

```
myProp.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file(project.currentModuleName + "/keystore.properties")))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528242/how-can-i-find-the-path-of-the-current-gradle-script

Answer (score 1):

You can store buildType/buildFlavor name as BuildConfig value. And use it like `BuildConfig.your_variable_name`.
To get current flavor/buildType use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621183/how-to-get-current-flavor-in-gradle).